# How to port Dojo animation that uses Curve to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have a piece of legacy code that uses dojo/animations/curve to do smooth scrolling.

```
    var anim = null;
    var animProps = new Object();
    animProps.duration = 100;
    animProps.beforeBegin = ss.mkdel(this, function() {
        var oldS = this._containerNode.domNode.scrollLeft;
        anim.curve = new dojo._Line(oldS, x);
    });
    animProps.onAnimate = ss.mkdel(this, function(val) {
        this._containerNode.domNode.scrollLeft = val;
    });
    animProps.onEnd = ss.mkdel(this, function() {
        this.$updateScrollButtons();
    });
    anim = new dojo._Animation(animProps);
```

I want to port it to jQuery, but obviously interfaces are not compatible.

In particular, jQuery does not have a notion of the curve.

So the question I have: how can this code be ported to jQuery?
Should I use Step function and manually calculate value?
http://api.jquery.com/animate/